# How to send parameter from jsp page to jasper file

Tags: jasper-reports

Now,I have jasper file add to netbean.
In JSP page i have 2 textbox for input 2 parameter , then after click "ok" it can show myreport catagorize by 2 parameter.

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can transmit the variables through a HashMap in which your variables in the JSP correspond to parameters in the jrxml.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this one:

[How to pass parameter value in JasperReport from JSP or Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867644/how-to-pass-parameter-value-in-jasper-report-from-jsp-java)

I don't fully understand your question, but if you want to show the parameters in your report instead of using it on the SQL query you only have to put it into a  tag

```
<textField>
     <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{parameterTest}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```